# _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE globally?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c-preprocessor, deprecated

I've found posts about disabling Warnings generated via `_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` on a per-project basis, but is there a way to set this globally, or one time to apply to all future projects?

I ask cause I'm in a C++ class and we create at least one new project per class. It's no big deal to add per project, but wondered if there was a more permanent solution.

Comment: You could create your own project template with it already defined, File + Export Template.  Or you could consider just writing secure code, no better time to start with that while you are still learning and haven't yet acquired the M$ sucks attitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a global option like an environment variable. And you really don't want that anyway.

I know of 2 methods to easily spread configurations including preprocessor definitions:

1. Create a header file with your favorite macro/types/whatever.
2. Create
   a prop file and have your project reference it. This is more complex.

Comment: It's for instances of strcpy vs strcpy_s and similar deprecated functions. but you're right; I don't want to permanently disable.  thanks for the feedback.